# Function returning list of different possible children classes

Tags: c#, bindingsource

I have a binding source which can be bound to a list of A or a list of B. Depending if it's A or B, when I click "Save" I want to call the save method of the appropriate repository.

I was able to create this method to check if any list is dirty and needs saving:

```
private static bool IsDirty<T>(TList<T> list) where T : IEntity, new()
{
    foreach (var entity in list)
    {
        if (entity.IsDirty)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, I am having a problem with the following:

```
var list = CurrentTList<A>();
```

and

```
private TList<T> CurrentTList<T>()  where T: IEntity, new()
{
    switch (currentRatesTable)
    {
        case RatesTables.A:
            return (TList<T>) _bindingSourceMaster.List;
        case RatesTables.B:
            return (TList<T>) _bindingSourceMaster.List;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to get my current list from the data source? I would like to avoid using a switch like so, as it doesn't look right to me:

```
switch (currentRatesTable)
{
    case Form1.RatesTables.A:
        var list = CurrentTList<A>();
    case Form1.RatesTables.B:
        var list = CurrentTList<B>();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It sounds like what you really need is an interface

Comment: What are you intending to do with the returned `list`? What is a `TList`?

Comment: A Tlist is a list -> public class TList<T> : ListBase<T> where T : IEntity, new() and ListBase Is
public abstract class ListBase<T> : BindingList<T>, IBindingListView, IBindingList, IList, ICloneable, ICloneableEx, IListSource, ITypedList, IDisposable, IComponent, IRaiseItemChangedEvents, IDeserializationCallback

Comment: the returned list will be passed as a parameter to the save method of my repository

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, as Sayse says, you need yourself an interface and/or an abstract class. If there's a lot of shared code, you can just start with the latter. Here's something riffed on from an old test project. It takes a different approach (each item in the collection is what's relevant as the 'dirty' thing, and there are excised methods that would search the collection for those), but you should be able to adapt as needed:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class Dirty : Object
{
    protected bool _isdirty;
    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get { return _isdirty; }
        set
        {
            _isdirty = value;
        }

}

public abstract class DataStore<T> where T : Dirty
{
    private string _path;
    private string _tempFile;

    protected DataStore(string path, string tempfile)
    {

        _path = path;
        _tempFile = tempfile;
    }
}
```

So DataStore held the logic to manipulate those lists. The idea for me was both classes that inherited from Dirty were being serialized to JSON, so as long as their members had the right attributes they all got properly serialized, and thus there was no custom logic for each class for its storage. Thus, all they had to do to create their datastore was:

```
  [DataContract]
    public class Account : Abstracts.Dirty
    {
        #region DataStore fields and singleton
        private static volatile StoreClass _store = new StoreClass();
        protected static StoreClass Store
        {
            get
            {
                return _store;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Store is the data store for the Account class. This holds the active list of Accounts in a singleton, and manages the push/pull to the JSON file storage.
        /// </summary>
        protected class StoreClass : Abstracts.DataStore<Account>
        {
            #region Singleton initialization and Constructor

            public StoreClass()
                : base("accounts.json", "TEMP_accounts.json")
            {

            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
```

I cut out a few thousand lines on this project just from the datastore, but it was pretty crazy. The basic idea is to build the logic you need into the DataStore class to save a list, and aim how you save/load it via how you call its constructor from the StoreClass child.

Comment: Just to explain because I'm not sure how clear its relation to your question was, use the concept of the DataStore to hold the logic to pull the right table, and you can have each list class have that as a field with a call to its constructor to target its origination point. Essentially you want to make them both their own classes so you can actually call them properly without having to do something like that switch that annoyed you so much. Make the application understand each as its own object and put their likely heavily-shared logic together for saving/loading under DataStore.